# Delphi: any way to link to a variable in a BPL that has not been PACKAGEd?

Tags: delphi, linker, vcl

I'm working on a project in RAD Studio 2007, using VCL classes in c++.

TDBLookupControl is part of VCL & has some undesirable behaviour, which is caused by use of an internal variable `SearchTickCount`

```
var
   SearchTickCount: Integer = 0; //file scope in DBCtrls.pas

procedure TDBLookupControl.ProcessSearchKey(Key: Char);
var
  TickCount: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
//some code removed for brevity
      TickCount := GetTickCount;
      if TickCount - SearchTickCount > 2000 then SearchText := '';
      SearchTickCount := TickCount;
//some code removed for brevity
end;
```

However, `SearchTickCount` has never been PACKAGEd inside the VCL, as in example below.

```
extern PACKAGE int SearchTickCount;
```

I'd like to set `SearchTickCount` to zero (on demand) in my c++ code.
Externing it in my code makes the c++ compile. However, the linker (obviously) cannot find the variable.

```
namespace Dbctrls
{
  extern int SearchTickCount;
}
// later on, inside a function
Dbctrls::SearchTickCount = 0;
```

Is there any way/workaround to link to this variable?

EDIT:
Unfortunately, we're also using some custom controls that derive from TDBLookupControl so I was tring to avoid creating more custom controls.

Comment: I don't believe there is a viable way to get at `SearchTickCount`.  On the other hand it would be plausible to change the meaning of `GetTickCount` for the duration of the call to `TDBLookupControl.ProcessSearchKey` if that would help.

Comment: If you are prepared to abandon runtime packages you could simply include a copy of DBCtrls.pas in your project (include it in the .dpr file) and then modify the source to suit your needs.

Comment: @David: Not prepared to abandon packages. Changing the meaning of `GetTickCoount` is one approach I haven't thought of. +1

Comment: @Chris I'm curious. Why are you wedded to packages?

Comment: @David: not really sure ... commandments are sent from above. We use a lot of thrid party components that come in packages ..

Comment: @Chris I see. I always add my 3rd party stuff to the project and link it all into one big exe. But that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int* s_TimerMemoryAddress;

union VTableHelper
{
    char* pointer;
    char** deref;
    unsigned int adjustment;
};

#pragma pack(1)
struct TInstructionHack
{
    WORD OpCodePrefix;
    int* OpCodeAddresss;
};

union FuncPtr
{
    TInstructionHack* Checker;
    char* Increment;
};
#pragma pack()
```

Since TDBLookupControl::ProcessSearchKey is virtual, a pointer to this function
doesn't return an actual non static member function pointer address.
Instead, it returns a vtable address, which points to a thunk
(a small bit of code that redirects the virtual function to correct derived
object non static member function). Below code figures out the final (non-virtual)
address of the member function TDBLookupControl::* ProcessSearchKey based on thunk

```
try
{
    std::auto_ptr<TDBLookupControlHelper> hack(new TDBLookupControlHelper);
    TDBLookupControlHelper* ptrptr = hack.get();

    VTableHelper thunk;
    thunk.pointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptrptr);
    thunk.pointer = *thunk.deref;       //get virtual table pointer
    //adjust for specific function pointer (TDBLookupControl::* ProcessSearchKey)
      as specified by thunk
    thunk.adjustment += 0xF4;       
    thunk.pointer = *thunk.deref;
    thunk.adjustment += 0x02;       //adjust for long jump instruction
    thunk.pointer = *thunk.deref;
    //get actual location of TDBLookupControl::ProcessSearchKey
    thunk.pointer = *thunk.deref;

    FuncPtr ptr;
    ptr.Increment = thunk.pointer;

    //2000 is completely arbitrary, only to prevent an infinite loop
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 2000 && s_TimerMemoryAddress == NULL; ++counter)
    {
         // Looking for SUB EAX, [SearchTickCount]
        if(ptr.Checker->OpCodePrefix == 0x052B)
            s_TimerMemoryAddress = ptr.Checker->OpCodeAddresss;
        else
            ptr.Increment++;
        counter++;
    }
}
catch(...) // catch any illegal dereferences of VTableHelper
{
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### The problem

`SearchTickCount` is a global (unit level) variable declared in the implementation section of the unit, it's not supposed to be accessed outside that unit. You'd have the same problem if you were working with Delphi, not C++ Builder.

### The sane solutions

- Subclass the `TDBLookupControl`, override `ProcessSearchKey()` and make sure it uses your own `SearchTickCount`, one that's easily accessible. Happily `ProcessSearchKey()` is virtual, in theory this should work, but in practice the code depends on `FListField`, that's a private field so we'll be back to square 1.
- Copy the whole `TDBLookupControl` to your own `TMyDBLookupControl` and make sure you can access the `SearchTickCount`. This would definitively work.

### The HACKY solution

Ofcourse, hacks are a lot more fun. The CPU has no problem finding the `SearchTickCount` because the address is coded into the ASM instructions that make up `ProcessSearchKey's` code. What the CPU can read, we can read.

Evaluating the code for the `ProcessSearchKey` method, it only uses one global variable (`SearchTickCount`) and it uses it in two places. First in this test:

```
if TickCount - SearchTickCount > 2000 then
```

then in this instruction:

```
SearchTickCount := TickCount;
```

If you look into the disassembly listing of that routine, global variable access is easily spotted, because it gives the address of the variable in square brackets, with no other qualifier. For the `if` to work the compiler does something like this:

```
SUB EAX, [$000000]
```

For the assignment, the compiler does something like this:

```
MOV [$000000], EAX // or ESI on Delphi 7 with debug enabled
```

If you look at the left of the assembler instruction, you can easily see the actual opcode, in HEX notation. For example the SUB EAX, [$000000] looks like this:

```
2B0500000000
```

My hacky solution exploits this. I get the address of the actual procedure (`TDBLookupControl.ProcessSearchKey`), scan the code looking for the opcode (`2B 05`) and grab the address. That's it, and it works.

Of course, this has potential problems. It depends on the code being compiled with those exact registers (`EAX` in my example). The compiler is free to choose different registers. I tested with both Delphi7 and Delphi 2010, with code compiled for Debug and compiled without Debug. In all 4 cases the compiler chose to use `EAX` for the `SUB` instruction, and in 3/4 cases chose to use `ESI` as the register for the `MOV` instruction. Because of that my code only looks for the `SUB` instruction.

On the other hand if the code works *once*, the code works every time. Code doesn't change once released, so if you can properly test on the development machine, you will not get nasty AV's at client's machine. But use at your own risk, this is, after all, a hack!

Here's the code:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses DbCtrls;

function GetSearchTickCountPointer: PInteger;

implementation

type
  THackDbLookupControl = class(TDBLookupControl); // Hack to get address of protected member
  TInstructionHack = packed record
    OpCodePrefix: Word;
    OpCodeAddress: PInteger;
  end;
  PInstructionHack = ^TInstructionHack;

function GetSearchTickCountPointer: PInteger;
var P: PInstructionHack;
    N: Integer;
begin
  P := @THackDbLookupControl.ProcessSearchKey;
  N := 0; // Sentinel counter, so we don't look for the opcode for ever
  while N < 2000 do
  begin
    if P.OpCodePrefix = $052B then // Looking for SUB EAX, [SearchTickCount]
    begin
      Result := P.OpCodeAddress;
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(N);
    P := PInstructionHack(Cardinal(P)+1); // Move pointer 1 byte
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;

end.
```

You use the hacky version like this:

```
var P: PInteger;
begin
  P := GetSearchTickCountPointer;
  if Assigned(P) then
    P^ := 1; // change SearchTickCount value!
end;
```

Comment: +1 I'd ruled out your two sane solutions, the first because of the private field and the second because OP is using packages.  Your opcode hunting solution would require complete control of package delivery. You wouldn't want to be using packages from system32 that might be changed when you install another app. If it was me I would not use packages (I never use them, I can't stand them) and I would simply include a copy of DBCtrls.pas in my project and modify the code to suit.

Comment: @David, the `SUB` instruction I'm hunting proved to be fairly stable, across two Delphi compiler versions with/without debug enabled. Unless someone changes the packages with a re-compiled version that doesn't use `SearchTickCount`, I wouldn't expect problems. And if someone does change packages, there are a lot more potential problems.

Comment: @Cosmin I agree with that. I'm just of a nervous disposition and I'd probably elect to put everything in my executable. In my code I change the default height for TButton from 25 to 23 with similar code to yours. But I make sure that StdCtrls.dcu is in my module rather than a package.

Comment: With the subclass private FListField can be gotten around by declaring a class with the exact same member field structure as TDBLookupControl and casting to that. Add some unit tests to check for changes in the instance size and/or alignment of the field members to alert you to changes in TDBLookupControl when switching Delphi versions. We use this to great effect on the TThread class to get at the private FTerminated flag...

Comment: +1 for 2 sane suggestions . I've ruled them both out because we also use thrid party controls that derive from `TDBLookupControl'.

Comment: @Chris Bednarski, in that case the hacky solution is for you, because it gives you a pointer to *the* `SearchTickCount`.

Comment: Couldn't you use a cracker class to access the private field?  Extracting the address of a variable from the assembly seems a very hacky solution - clever, but fragile.

Comment: @David M, the OP needs to gain access to a global variable defined in the implementation section of `DbCtrls.pas` unit: no "cracker" class is going to give you that. A different hack based on @Marjan's idea is possible, but considering the OP needs the solution to be compatible with 3rd party packages that depend on `TDBLookupControl`, the @Marjan hack needs to be followed with the insertion of a `JMP` instruction in the code block that implements the old procedure. Ie: modifying one's executable code at runtime. I'm tempted to say the hack I'm proposing is the least intrusive.

Comment: @Cosmin: I meant using it to access `FListField`, not `SearchTickCount`.  From what I understand of how it works, subclassing the control would solve the problem if you could access the private fields, and using a cracker would let you do so.  But I see it's the third-party packages that are the problem - they inherit from that class, and I didn't see that bit :) @Chris: you don't have the source to these packages?

Comment: @Cosmin: ProcessSearchKey is virtual so `@THackDbLookupControl.ProcessSearchKey` returns an address of vtable, so the hacky solution doesn't work

Comment: @Cosmin: I have indeed ... and needed to figure out how virtual tables are implemented by Borland C++ compiler to get it to work. The idea is sane but doesn't work as described in this answer. I even thought that having a Delphi unit would make a difference but there was no way around getting the virtual address. I'll post the working hack back when I'm at work.

Answer (score 0):

### Another 2 options:

### Hacky

- cut my own VCL

Fix the problematic implementation and make sure all packages work with my own version of VCL

### Sane

- avoid fkData and fkInternalCalc fields in `TDBLookupControl`s

I missed this implementation detail before. `SearchTickCount` is checked only if the field kind is fkData or fkInternalCalc. Having calculated fields (fkCalculated) should totally avoid the problem.

Comment: If with your Hacky solution you're suggesting re-compiling your own version of a VCL package, it will not work unless you re-compile everything that depends on that package, including all 3rd party packages: in order to gain access to the `SearchTickCount` you'd need to make changes in the `interface` section of that unit, and once you do that you'll get the "unit was compiled with different version of" error. The sane solution looks good.